# import graphlab does not work properly

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I am a beginner in graphlab create. I have Python 3 installed on my system and I am working on jupyter notebook with the help of graph create launcher.

When I try to import graphlab the following notification comes up:

```
ACTION REQUIRED: Dependencies libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found.

1. Ensure user account has write permission to C:\Users\bandriya\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab
2. Run graphlab.get_dependencies() to download and install them.
3. Restart Python and import graphlab again.

By running the above function, you agree to the following licenses.

* libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
* xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this line on your ipython notebook:

```
graphlab.get_dependencies()
```

You should see this:

By running this function, you agree to the following licenses.

- libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
- xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING

Downloading xz.
Extracting xz.
Downloading gcc-libs.
Extracting gcc-libs.
Copying gcc-libs into the installation directory.

Once that's done, exit your notebook then restart it. You should be able to import graphlab.
I think certain dependencies or modules have not been downloaded properly when you installed graphlab on your computer.